# height does not change in XML

Tags: android, xml

Really I feel very sick

the height for text view does not change

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center"

        />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i try a lot of time but nothing happened

Comment: Your TextView is ok. Give us more details, full layout xml for example.

Comment: its height change just when I change the textSize

Comment: Are you using it in inflate function? if you do so inform us. if not you can use weight_sum property in scroolView. Using dp probably is not useful.

Comment: I dont use it in inflate func ... 
i try to replace dp by px ,,,, but nothing happen

Comment: @Maysara, please give more concrete description of your codes instead of just "feeling sick". Debugging is not easy, we all know it. Thats why stackoverflow is.

Comment: dude ,,,, this is the first layout in project ,,, the project is empty .... just there is an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a LinearLayout inside your ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/linear">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also change the height of the LinearLayout to 100dp so by default whether there would be 100dp space reserved for LinearLayout/TextView (whether there are any text or not in the TextView)

PS: It is a good practice to have to a LinearLayout inside your scrollView. It will be easier to control and keep your child objects aligned.

I hope it worked. Cheers.

Comment: its work ,,,, but this will make my project slow ,,, is not it ?

Comment: @Maysara, No it's not. If you are adding Text in TextView from your code (by calling it's id), it might take ~1 seconds to load if the text is way too much. But you should take a peek on how much your TextView can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. And since your child is of fixed height, so is the parent element.

Comment: for sorry  ,,, i need to give it a fixed area :)

Answer (score 1):

OK - so you have set your scrollview to:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This actually doesn't make sense as you are suppose to be able to scroll the view to see more item. That is the purpose of scrollview. In general, scrollviews are normally match_parent. Change the xml to the below for scroll value and it should work.

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: for sorry ,,, it does not work for me 
 
its height change just when I change the textSize

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the layout you are using. I have used the following LinearLayout and the size of the your textview changes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
```